# Object animator restarting even with setRepeatCount = 0

Tags: java, android, objectanimator

I'm using `ObjectAnimator` to animate the progress of a [WaveView](https://github.com/john990/WaveView). 

In this method (which is called from my Activity `onCreate()`) I trigger the animation using `waveAnimator.start()`, *waterLevel* is my `WaveView`

```
void setCurrentLevel(int currentLevelValue) {
    // Animate WaveView
    ObjectAnimator waveAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(waterLevel, "progress", currentLevelValue);
    waveAnimator.setDuration(500);
    waveAnimator.start();
}
```

This is my `WaveView` in *activity_main.xml*

```xml
<com.john.waveview.WaveView
    android:id="@+id/water_level"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:above_wave_color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:blow_wave_color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:wave_height="little"
    app:wave_hz="normal"
    app:wave_length="middle"/>
```

The problem is that for some reason, the animation is being displayed twice, as you can see in this [gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuXue.jpg)

Adding a `Listener` to my `ObjectAnimator` I can see that the animation is started, then `onAnimationEnd` is called, then the animation is started again and eventually `onAnimationEnd` is called for the second time.

I tried to add `waveAnimator.setRepeatCount(0)` but nothing changes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that `setCurrentLevel()` is only being called once?

Comment: @BenP. I need to check it because `setCurrentLevel` is called after I fetch data from Firebase Cloud Firestore. I also have a snapshot listener on that Firebase collection so the problem might be there